# For upgrade Django 1.9.7 to 1.9.9 "webpackJsonp is not defined" appears in admin page menu

Tags: django, django-cms

I am testing some elements of Django-cms with django, when I upgrade from django 1.9.7 to Django 1.9.9 javascript error on admin Django-Cms on  menus Page "webpackJsonp is not defined" issued from the static bundle .../cms/js/dist/bundle.admin.pagetree.js. After some Google turnaround, trouble seems linked to bundle building. I downgrade to django 1.9.7 and it's ok

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Pagetree bundle `/cms/js/dist/bundle.admin.pagetree.min.js` cannot really be used without `/cms/js/dist/bundle.admin.base.min.js` included before it.

What is also important is to reference them using `{% static_with_version %}` template tags that come from `cms_static` library.

Comment: Thanks for your interest, I will re-install 1.9.9, in two days from now, and I will let you know the result.

Comment: I roll back to django 1.9.9, so as I was facing some releases mismatches , I do several adaptations,  to be honest I can't say what has impacted positively  the system, and after that I introduce also your template tag. I have to be more cautious with releases conflict, I think. Thanks for help